# mySql Delete only removes the data not the entire entry

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi all I have this line in my php code

```
 `$insert = "DELETE FROM allocation_table WHERE job = '$jobnumber' " ;
  Mysql_query ($insert) ;`
```

The problem is it will remove all the values from the one line in my table but not the entry itself. as you can see in the picture if I delete where job = 315 , it does not delete the line but does delete all the entries

Yet in this code that preceeds it (a different table) . it works fine and the whole line is removed

```
$insert = "DELETE FROM event WHERE jobnumber = '$jobnumber' " ; 
mysql_query ($insert) ;enter code here
```

can anyone offer some advice please ?? [alt text http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/4431/tablenj.jpg](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/4431/tablenj.jpg)

Comment: Isn't the job with id = 315 being referenced anywhere by other tables?

Comment: The image you uploaded is not loading

Comment: @Mick This problem would occur in case your database tables have foreign key relationships and you are trying to remove child but the parent is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error handling routines in your code?
You might also want to add some debug output (or even better use a debugger like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/))
(oversimplified) example:

```
$insert = "DELETE FROM allocation_table WHERE job = '$jobnumber' " ;
echo '<pre>Debug: query=', htmlspecialchars($insert), '</pre>';
$rc = mysql_query($insert);
if ( !$rc ) {
  echo '<pre>mysql_query failed: ', mysql_error(), '</pre>';
}
else {
  echo '<pre>Debug: affected rows=', mysql_affected_rows(), '</pre>';
}

$insert = "DELETE FROM event WHERE jobnumber = '$jobnumber' " ; 
echo '<pre>Debug: query=', htmlspecialchars($insert), '</pre>';
$rc = mysql_query($insert);
if ( !$rc ) {
  echo '<pre>mysql_query failed: ', mysql_error(), '</pre>';
}
else {
  echo '<pre>Debug: affected rows=', mysql_affected_rows(), '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Yes i do (removed for clarity though) but either way the entry is not removed just the data 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some weird setting on your MySQL table that is causing the query to function differently. Did you create the table yourself (with PMA?) or import it from somewhere else?

When you delete using PHPMyAdmin, what is the query that it runs?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting in PhpMyAdmin and see what happens.  At least there you'll be able to easily see any error message.

Do you have foreign keys defined and/or table constraints?